# insert space after each flextable in r (Rmd)

Tags: r, tidyverse, flextable, officer, officedown

i have this problem:

**Problem:**

I have multiple flextable objects in a same r chunk:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  flextable()

mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  flextable()
```

But when i knit the Rmd in a `officedown::rdocx_document` the tables appear stick together like this:
[image: tables stick]
This is a problem because having multiple tables stick changes the sizes of the following tables and its taken by Word as a single big table. So i manage to solve it this way:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(officedown)

mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  flextable()

officer::run_linebreak()

mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  flextable()
```

Now tables have a line or Enter in between. So what i want to do know is to join this two functions into one so that i don't have to use two different functions. Something like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  table_and_enter()

mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  table_and_enter()
```

What i actually want is a space between tables so if you find a more efficient way to do it feel free to suggest.

**Objetive:**

- Insert a line (an Enter) after each flextable object with a single line of code.

**Attempts:**

- Apparently a function in r can't retrieve an object and a function even if you use return() multiple times.

Thanks.

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Comment: I get two separate tables when I run the code in the top code block, and there are no vertical lines in the output. Also the `return` function is not a carriage return. It is designed to send values from inside a function to the calling environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a caption fixes it. Here, I added blank captions:

```
ft <- mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  flextable()
ft <- set_caption(ft, "")
ft


ft <- mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  head() %>% 
  flextable()
ft <- set_caption(ft, "")
ft
```

I ran this in a R markdown chunk with echo = FALSE and used the word_ouput option. The result is nicely separated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want return() to return multiple objects from a function you can put the objects in a list and return the list.

```
my_fun <- function(x, y){
  x = x+1
  y = x*y
  
  the_list <- list(x, y)
  
  return(the_list)
}

my_fun(3, 4)
```

Comment: thanks kpress for the response. Its not quite im looking for because when i knitr my officedown document with the solution you suggest it appears like this: [[1]]

[[2]]
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "run_linebreak" "run"